# counting number of characters per each line(rich textbox) in statusstrip in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have almost designed a notepad using c#. But only problem I'm facing now is in my statusstrip.

> My need- I want to display character count per each line.

When user press enter key it should come to new line and now character count should start from 1.

Technically - Col=1, Ln=1; //(initially)Col=no of character per line Ln=line count
              When user press enter key-
              Ln=2 and goes on and Col=No of characters we have typed in that          specific line
I've tried these lines of code -

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) != 13)
        {
            Col = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Col:" + Col.ToString() + "," + "Ln:" + Ln;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 13)
        {
            //richTextBox1.Clear(); 
            Ln = Ln + 1;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Col:" + Col.ToString() + "Ln:" + Ln;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If u're not getting my requirements then please open ur notepad and click on view-status bar and u can easily understand my requirement

Comment: so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are using Windows Forms, you can use the following solution (but you have to subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event instead of the `KeyPress` event of the rich text box control):

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

    // Get the line number of the cursor.
    Ln = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(currentIndex);

    // Get the index of the first char in the specific line.
    int firstLineCharIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(Ln);

    // Get the column number of the cursor.
    Col = currentIndex - firstLineCharIndex;

    // The found indices are 0 based, so add +1 to get the desired number.
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Col:" + (Col + 1) + "   Ln:" + (Ln + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanx man.. It worked _/\_ respect for u .. almost I banged my head for that problem.. Thanx again :)